# Using a List (Spark List Control) as a Spark Datagrid Column Item renderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5, flex-spark

I have the following problem:

I need to create a dynamic datagrid, but the content of the cells are an `ArrayCollection`.
I'm trying to use the Spark List Control, as the item renderer of each column, but is not working properly.

Does anyone already had to do something similar or know a good example of the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: it would help if you could post your code

Comment: please explain what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution, it's something like:

```
<s:GridItemRenderer>    

<s:List id="eventsGroup" borderVisible="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0" useVirtualLayout="false"`>
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout variableRowHeight="true"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

And then we can just add a simple item renderer for each List element.